# get content, row to column and csv edited

Tags: csv, powershell

I get-content and select string from multiple files in a directory
so I get lines like this for every file in the folder, I get the lines with host and the users, then the next file.

```
Host: blah.blah
OS: "Windows 7"
"Windows User","bc","btfr1","Internal user for"
"Windows User","bc3","btfr2","user for"
"Windows User","bc8","btfr3","user"
"Windows User","bc2","btfr4","something"

Host: bleh.bleh
OS: "Windows 8.1"
"Windows User","cb5","frtb5","External user for"
"Windows User","cb2","frtb2","user"
"Windows User","cb6","frtb1","add files for"
```

I want a form like this to be produced next:

```
"blah.blah","Windows 7","Windows User","bc","btfr1","Internal user for"
"blah.blah","Windows 7","Windows User","bc3","btfr2","user for"
"blah.blah","Windows 7","Windows User","bc8","btfr3","user"
"blah.blah","Windows 7","Windows User","bc2","btfr4","something"
"bleh.bleh","Windows 8.1","Windows User","cb5","frtb5","External user for"
"bleh.bleh","Windows 8.1","Windows User","cb2","frtb2","user"
"bleh.bleh","Windows 8.1","Windows User","cb6","frtb1","add files for"
```

or:

```
"Windows 7","blah.blah","Windows User","bc","btfr1","Internal user for"
"Windows 7","blah.blah","Windows User","bc3","btfr2","user for"
"Windows 7","blah.blah","Windows User","bc8","btfr3","user"
"Windows 7","blah.blah","Windows User","bc2","btfr4","something"
"Windows 8.1","bleh.bleh","Windows User","cb5","frtb5","External user for"
"Windows 8.1","bleh.bleh","Windows User","cb2","frtb2","user"
"Windows 8.1","bleh.bleh","Windows User","cb6","frtb1","add files for"
```

The code is written below.

```
Set-Location c:/mine
Get-Content *.csv `
| Select-String -pattern 'OS|Host|"Windows User"'| Set-Content results.csv
$text = Get-Content results.csv

$OutData = foreach ($str in $text) {
if ($str -match '^Host:\s.*$') {
    # get prefix
    $prefix = $str -replace '^Host:\s?(.*)$','$1'
}
elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($str)) {
    # Do not touch empty strings!
}
else {
    # generate out string with matched prefix
    $outString = "`"$prefix`",$str"
    Write-Output $outString


  }
}

$OutData | Out-File results.csv -Force -Encoding utf8
```

I thought of getting one more "if" after that for the job but the table gets one more line that always changes according to the host name so I can't have it as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$text = Get-Content *.csv

$OutData = foreach ($str in $text) {

    if ($str -match '^Host:\s.*$') {
        # get prefix
        $prefix = $str -replace '^Host:\s?(.*)$','$1'
    }
    elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($str)) {
        # Do not touch empty strings!
    }
    else {
        # generate out string with matched prefix
        $outString = "`"$prefix`",$str"
        Write-Output $outString
    }
}

$OutData | Out-File results.csv -Force -Encoding utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

finally done it the code in foreach must be changed to:

```
foreach ($str in $text) {

    if ($str -match '^Host:\s.*$') {
        # get prefix
        $prefix = $str -replace '^Host:\s?(.*)$','$1'
    }
    elseif ($str -match '^OS:\s.*$') {
        # get prefix2
        $prefix2 = $str -replace '^OS:\s?(.*)$','$1'
    }

    elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($str)) {
        # Do not touch empty strings!
    }
    else {
        # generate out string with matched prefix
        $outString = "$prefix2`"$prefix`",$str"
        Write-Output $outString
    }
}
```